# How to use like to return data also in case of empty values

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have an `SQL` `script` which returns 3 data: `Product`, `Category` and `Subcategory`
I would like to be possible to filter from the returned list based on Product, Category and also SubCategory. I need to use always all the three item in the filter.
I'm using the `Like` keyword
If I use for filtering only the `ProductType` it can be seen that I have a lot of elements where `Category` and `Subcategory` are null

[image]

But if I add to filter also for Category and Subcategory, if I add the `like` like in the screenshot, I don't get back all the elements, (I thought that in this case I will get back the same result as in the previous screenshot), but I get back this

[image]

I've tried like this,

[image]

here I thought that I will get back all the items where the Product has an 's' in the name and where the Category has a 'b', so this would be the expected result in  this case

[image]

Can you please advise how can I use the `like` keyword to do the job properly? Thanks!

Comment: Next time please don't use images, but paste code and data into your request as text. This helps us use your code and data to find a solution for you. Please also read: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have:

```
where producttype like '%S%'
  and category like '%b%' or category is null
  and subcategory like '%%' or subcategory is null
```

But `AND` has precedence over `OR`, so this translates to

```
where (producttype like '%S%' and category like '%b%')
   or (category is null and subcategory like '%%')
   or (subcategory is null)
```

So, add parentheses to get what you want:

```
where producttype like '%S%'
  and (category like '%b%' or category is null)
  and (subcategory like '%%' or subcategory is null)
```

You should always use parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your want

```
WHERE ProductType LIKE '%s%' AND Category LIKE '%b%'
```

This logic make your result wrong, it makes you get Category which has "b" character
or is null

```
Category LIKE '%b%' OR Category IS NULL
```